# Is it possible to prove/check this when there is no closed-form solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let the space of n by n real symmetric positive definite matrices be called $SPD(n)$.

Let $f(x_1,...,x_i)$ be the mapping from $SPD(n)^i$ to $SPD(ni)$ such that the output of $f$ is a block diagonal matrix of the form:

$f(x_1,...,x_i) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} & 0_{n} & \cdots & 0_{n} \\
0_{n} & x_{2} & \cdots & 0_{n} \\
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
0_{n} & 0_{n} & \cdots & x_{i} 
\end{pmatrix}$

where the sequence of input matrices, $\{x_1,...,x_i\} \in SPD(n)^i$.

The Riemannian mean of $m$ SPD matrices (which has no closed-form solution) is given by:

$G(x_1,...,x_m) = \underset{x \in SPD(n)}{\operatorname{argmin}} \sum^m_{i=1} \delta^{2}_{R}(x,x_i)$

where the Riemannian distance, $\delta_R$, between 2 SPD matrices, $x_1$ and $x_2$ $\in SPD(n)$ is:

$\delta_R(x_1,x_2) = \lvert \lvert Log(x_1^{-1}x_2) \rvert \rvert_F  = \left( \sum^n_{i=1} log^2 \lambda_i \right)^\frac{1}{2} $

where $Log(.)$ is the matrix logarithm, $\lvert\lvert.\rvert\rvert_F$ is the Frobenius norm of a matrix and $\lambda_i$ are the real strictly positive eigenvalues of $x^{-1}_1x_2$. See [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis610/geomean.pdf) for more info on $G$ & $\delta_R$

For $J$ sequences of matrices, each of length $i$, in $SPD(n)$ such that:

$ Q = \left( Q_1,...,Q_J\right)$

and $Q_j = (x_1,...,x_i) \in SPD(n)^i$

and so that the $i^{th}$ element of the $j^{th}$ sequence is written as $Q_{ji}$

let:

$Q' = f(G(Q)) = f(G(Q_{11},...,Q_{1i}),...,G(Q_{j1},...,Q_{ji}))$

and

$\overline{Q} = G(f(Q)) =  G( f(Q_{11},...,Q_{j1}),...,f(Q_{1i},...,Q_{ji}) )$

I would like to know/check if (or for what cases) $Q' = \overline{Q}$?

Or in other words, I want to know if it matters whether I find the means of sequences of matrices and then map them to a single matrix with $f$ or whether I map the $i^{th}$ element of each sequence with $f$ first, and then find the resulting mean of that group.

I *think* I have shown that $Q' = \overline{Q}$ for $i=2$ since there is a closed form solution to the Riemannian mean of 2 SPD matrices (the closed form solution is in the link I shared) and so with some googling I calculated both matrices and they were the same. But is it possible to deduce anything about $i > 2$? I'm not a mathematician, so I don't really know where to start when dealing with objects that have no closed-form solution. A point in the right direction would be as helpful to me as the answer.